# How to fix "VirtualBox VM quit unexpectedly" when running my Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS VM on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1 in VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, macos

I am running Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 7.0.6_BETA4 on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1 and when I start my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VM it says "VirtualBox VM quit unexpectedly". How can I fix this?

The Apple report is below

```
    -------------------------------------
    Translated Report (Full Report Below)
    -------------------------------------
    
    Process:               VirtualBoxVM [6948]
    Path:                  /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources/VirtualBoxVM.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBoxVM
    Identifier:            org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBoxVM
    Version:               7.0.6 (7.0.6)
    Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:        VBoxSVC [6878]
    Responsible:           VirtualBox [6872]
    User ID:               501
    
    Date/Time:             2023-01-17 21:47:11.6748 -0500
    OS Version:            macOS 13.0.1 (22A400)
    Report Version:        12
    Anonymous UUID:        397352F2-45B9-435E-CCBC-B496BE6093A4
    
    Sleep/Wake UUID:       63AA6DA0-AA9F-42F2-83A2-0D31F08C74C5
    
    Time Awake Since Boot: 28000 seconds
    Time Since Wake:       1893 seconds
    
    System Integrity Protection: enabled
    
    Crashed Thread:        9  EMT-0
    
    Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    
    Application Specific Information:
    abort() called
```

Comment: Does VirtualBox provide any debugging logs?

Comment: this is the only report I got, I'm not sure if there is any debugging logs.

Comment: VirtualBox had logs the last time I used it on Windows

Comment: VBox 7.0.x is still considered a beta release, I'd use 6.1.42 instead.